# I am waiting for you for a long time

Tags: grammar

I waited for him about 1 hour.

I told him:

> "I am waiting for you so long."
>
> "I am waiting for you for a long time."

Do they sound grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sentences are grammatically incorrect as they're in the wrong tense. *I am waiting for you* is in the present tense. If you want to reference a length of time you've been in the 'waiting' state, you want to modify the sentence to use present perfect tense, as the length of time you've been waiting has already occurred. Correcting your sample sentences:

> I **have been** waiting for you **for** so long.
>
> I **have been** waiting for you for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Both the sentences are ungramatical.

When you talk about how long something has been happening, you use the present perfect continuous, not the present continuous.  For examples:

I have been playing for two hours.

I have been studying for a long time.

So if you are still waiting for him, you should say:

I have been waiting for you so long.

I have been waiting for you for a long time.